# Sending different array of data via UIActivityViewController options

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an array of items to share. For example: string item and image item. How can I achieve if all options except an AirDrop sharing would use this type of data and Airdrop would use custom object?

i tried to use `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` but this delegate method works only if I return a single object, so returning array does nothing.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm fairly sure you can only send one thing at a time.

Comment: There are many ideas to do this, simple one would be zip your items and airdrop it across.